# Big problem with iOS app in Xcode for Launch Screen Update

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-simulator, launch-screen

As title I have a big problem with my iOS app.

I'm working on an update of launch screen of my app and have make several layouts modification.

After modification I have launch the app on simulator and on the physical device but it's possible to se the new launch screen, it appare the old launch screen and not how it appare on the storyboard now.

I have try a lot of possible solution find in the apple developer forum and on Stack but nothings of these work for me.

Help me I'm in Hell....

Comment: Prints please...

Comment: Things to try... 1) `Product -> Clean Build Folder`. 2) Delete the app from the simulator / device before re-running the app.

Comment: Wesley I don't understand you

Comment: The DonMag suggestion work well, I hope that this issue work only from Xcode and not after the store app upload